# check using regexp if date format in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using regexp to check if the non empty entries in an array are date format

I am using this-

```
unction isDateOrEmpty(array){
  let result = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
    //var date = new Date(array[i]);
    var regex = new RegExp("^\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2,4}$");
    if (array[i] != '') {
      if (regex.test(array[i]) == false){
      result[i+2] = "Not Date format";
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
```

I want this to check for month/date/year format where the month and date can be either 2 digits or 1, for example - 05 or 5. year can be two digits or four digits like 2022 or 22.

I am getting "Not Date format" for valid entries as well.

I also used

```
var date = new Date(array[i]);
isNaN(date.getTime())
```

but this also passes when there is just decimal entry

is this is right way to check for date format or is any better way?

Example  -

```
array  = [3/31/19, 8/22/2021, 2/1/2022, 34, test]
```

the check should identify the 34 and test as non date entries

Screenshot of data -
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Try this: `Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]'`

Comment: About `date format` of `I am using regexp to check if the non empty entries in an array are date format`, is this the date object or the string value, or is both included? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike - san, I checked the type of array[i]'s and all are object types, the array can contain dates as month/date/year format where the month and date can be either 2 digits or 1, for example - 05 or 5. year can be two digits or four digits like 2022 or 22.

The array can also contain decimal entries such as '34' or any strings such as 'test'

The check should identify these non date entries.

I have also update the question with an example

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `I checked the type of array[i]'s and all are object types` and `the array can contain dates as month/date/year format where the month and date can be either 2 digits or 1, for example - 05 or 5.`. In your situation, which are `3/31/19`, `8/22/2021`, `2/1/2022` of `array  = [3/31/19, 8/22/2021, 2/1/2022, 34, test]` the string values or the date object? In your reply, you say `all are object types`. But you also say  `dates as month/date/year format`. I'm confusing it. I apologize for this.

Comment: no problem @Tanaike -san, I have attached screenshot of a snippet of data in the question above, Hope it helps. 

So in the case of the data in screenshot `test` and `34` are not data format, I want their position to be saved in `result` . Please let me know if you need any more info

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm worried that you might not be able to understand my comment. I would like to know whether your date is the string value or the date object. But, unfortunately, from your reply and updated question, I cannot still understand it. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation? If you cannot understand that your date is the string value or the date object, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? By this, I can confirm it.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I am sorry for not understanding correctly. Here is the sample spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ytGhC9K7yM-eF_zET4SmFvKaRCqbgkTdfj5FLg_EDnM/edit#gid=0

In the case of spreadsheet, I want to identify which rows do not have dates as entries, here, rows 1526 and 1527 do not have date entries

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided sample Spreadsheet, your date values are the date object. In this case, `instanceof` can be used for checking the cell value is the date object. I posted a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your provided Spreadsheet, I could know that your date values are the date object. In this case, in order to confirm whether the value is the date object, `instanceof` can be used. When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

In this case, from your provided Spreadsheet, it supposes that the values are put in column "B". Please be careful about this.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const range = sheet.getRange("B2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const strValues = range.getDisplayValues();
  const res = range.getValues().map(([b], i) => {
    if (strValues[i][0] && b instanceof Date) {
      return `Value ${strValues[i][0]} of cell B${i + 2} is Date.`;
    } else if (!strValues[i][0]) {
      return `Cell B${i + 2} is empty.`;
    }
    return `Value ${b} of cell B${i + 2} is ${typeof b}.`;
  });
  console.log(res);
  
  DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
}
```

- When this script is run, the following result is shown in the log. And also, this result is exported as a text file by `DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))`. You can see it in the root folder.

  ```json
  [
    "Value 9/30/2019 of cell B2 is Date.",
    "Cell B3 is empty.",
    "Cell B4 is empty.",
    "Cell B5 is empty.",
    "Cell B6 is empty.",
    "Cell B7 is empty.",
    "Cell B8 is empty.",
    "Cell B9 is empty.",
    "Value 1/31/2019 of cell B10 is Date.",
    "Cell B11 is empty.",
    "Cell B12 is empty.",
    "Value 6/30/2020 of cell B13 is Date.",
    "Cell B14 is empty.",
    "Value 10/1/2020 of cell B15 is Date.",
    "Value 12/31/2019 of cell B16 is Date.",
    "Value 11/30/2021 of cell B17 is Date.",
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ]
  ```

#### Reference:

- [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike - san, works as expected

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.